# Check if point is in circular sector

Tags: java, math

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164240/java-how-to-check-of-a-point-is-inside-a-sliceof-a-circle) that deals with the same issue. The provided answers work, but I need to change it slightly for my case. Below is the answer I went with:

```
double theta = Math.atan2(pointerY - height / 2, pointerX - width / 2);

if(theta<0)
    theta = Math.PI - theta;
int whichSlice = 0;
double sliceSize = Math.PI*2 / 4;
double sliceStart;

for(int i=1; i<=4; i++) {
    sliceStart = i*sliceSize;
    if(theta < sliceStart) {
        whichSlice = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

In my case, I need to rotate the quadrants by 45 degrees. Below is an example; red is what this code does, while green is what I want:

[image]

I've tried various code alterations, but still can't figure it out.

Comment: You'd probably have to compare `theta` to two values: the starting angle of a slice, and the ending angle of the slice. Then see if `theta` is between both values. If yes, it's in the slice. If not, you go on to the next angles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

First off, create your circle in it's own desperate JComponent, and add it's own listeners - basically create a class for this circle, make the circle itself receive mouse  events, and MAKE SURE THAT THE CIRCLE OCCUPIES THE ENTIRE RECTANGLE OF THE JCOMPONENT - it must be touching all edges (I will be using this.getHeight() and this must return the height of the bounding box of the circle)!!!

Fixed code below to support such a case, in addition to support y axis which increases downwards:

Step 1:
Check if we are inside the circle.
Step 2:
Check if we are above/below the diagonal lines (note: equations for diagonal lines are y = x, and y = -x)

```
Point pointWeAreChecking;
Point centerOfCircle;
double radius;




if(Math.pow(Math.pow(pointWeAreChecking.x-centerOfCircle.x , 2) + Math.pow(pointWeAreChecking.y-centerOfCircle.y , 2), 0.5) <= radius)
{
//Means we are in circle.
if(pointWeAreChecking.y>pointWeAreChecking.x)
{
//Means it is either in 2 or 3 (it is below y = -x line)
if(pointWeAreChecking.y>-pointWeAreChecking.x + this.getHeight()){
//We are in 2.
}else
{
//We are in 3.    
}
}else
{
if(pointWeAreChecking.y>-pointWeAreChecking.x + this.getHeight())
{
//We are in 4.
}else
{
//We are in 2.
}
}

 }
```

Comment: But that only works for four quadrants, and if they're rotated exactly 45 degrees.

Comment: Isn't that what you want?

Comment: The basic method: Step 1 - test if in circle. 2 - use the equations of the lines (can be any degree rotation, any # of lines)

Comment: I tried the above code, but I'm only getting two numbers: 1 and 4.

Comment: You are correct. The answer above would only work in a normal x y plane - one which is centered around the origin of your circle, and y increases upwards (unlike java). To be able to create code that would work for your case, we should first isolate the circle object you created into it's own graphics plane, and then analyze the hit coordinates for a y axis which increases downward (like in java). I will look into this tomorrow

Comment: Fixed code. Try now please. REMEMBER: You must create a new class for your circle!! Make that class extend JComponent and attach the mouse listeners to it! Also, make sure your circle takes up the entire bounds of the JComponent!! Lastly, only then do u need to add the Circle JComponent to the rest of your graphics

Comment: Sorry, just got home. Yes, the provided code worked exactly as I needed. Thanks!